# Create tabular depending on counter

Tags: tables, expl3, latex3

I want to create a tabular with `i+2` many columns where `i` is a counter. The tabular should have the following layout:

```
-------------------------------
| 1 | 2 | ... | i | foo | bar |
-------------------------------
```

That means, the first row should have a `1` as content and the second a 2 and so on until `i` and the last two rows should have `foo` resp. `bar` as their content.

I tried it with a LaTeX3 while loop but of course this does not work as intended:

```
\int_new:N \l_loop_ctr_int
\int_zero:N \l_loop_ctr_int
\begin{tabular}{
  \int_while_do:nn {\l_loop_ctr_int < \arabic{i}}{l \int_incr:N \l_loop_ctr_int}
  ll
}
\int_zero:N \l_loop_ctr_int
\int_while_do:nn {\l_loop_ctr_int < \arabic{i}}{\int_incr:N \l_loop_ctr_int &}
foo & bar \\
\end{tabular}
```

Does anyone has a hint for me?

Comment: `\value{i}` instead of `\arabic{i}`, but I would not call the counter `i`, but I fear the loop isn't expandable in the column specifier argument of `tabular`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion the `\int_....` loop do not expand correctly in `\begin{tabular}{....}`, but generating the column specifiers before and storing them in token list works.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\newcounter{ictr}
\setcounter{ictr}{10}
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn


\int_new:N \ictr_int 
\int_set:Nn \ictr_int {\value{ictr}}
\int_step_inline:nnnn {1}{1}{\ictr_int}{%
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {l}
}
\begin{tabular}{\tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl ll}
  \int_step_inline:nnnn {1}{1}{\ictr_int}{#1 &}
  foo & bar \\
\end{tabular}

    \par
\setcounter{ictr}{20}
\int_set:Nn \ictr_int {\value{ictr}}
\int_step_inline:nnnn {1}{1}{\ictr_int}{%
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {l}
}
\begin{tabular}{\tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl ll}
  \int_step_inline:nnnn {1}{1}{\ictr_int}{#1 &}
  foo & bar \\
\end{tabular}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

[image]

Update with a macro:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\newcounter{ictr}
\setcounter{ictr}{10}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \ictr_int 
\newcommand{\testfoobar}[1]{%
  \tl_clear:N \l_tmpa_tl
  \int_set:Nn \ictr_int {#1}
  \int_step_inline:nnnn {1}{1}{\ictr_int+2}{%  Use 2 more columns
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {l}
  }
\begin{tabular}{\l_tmpa_tl}
  \int_step_inline:nnnn {1}{1}{\ictr_int}{##1 &}
  foo & bar \\
\end{tabular}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}
\testfoobar{\value{ictr}}

\foreach \x in {1,...,20} {%
\testfoobar{\x}

}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is a very nice solution! However, I still get some compile time error when I try to put the code inside a macro: `\newcommand\testfoobar{<your code here>}` if I call the macro inside begin/end-document I get the following error: `! Illegal parameter number in definition of \testfoobar`. Do you have any hint for me?

Comment: @MaxMaier: I'll update

Comment: @MaxMaier: See the update please -- The reason why your version fails is most likely due to `#1` inside of the macro -- You have to use `##1` then, since there is an implicit definition of a macro inside (the `\int_step_inline:nnnn` does this) and this needs the `##1` to access the current integer number

Comment: Thank you very much for your explainations. I learned a lot!

Comment: @MaxMaier: You're welcome. Happy TeXing!

Answer (score 3):

`\int_while_do:nn` cannot start in a table cell and end in another one.

You can use `\prg_replicate:nn` that delivers the whole thing at once, though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\maiertable}{mmm}
 {% #1 = number of columns (minus 2), #2 and #3 = last two cells
  \begin{tabular}{|*{\int_eval:n { #1 + 2 }}{c|}}
  \hline
  \int_zero:N \g_tmpa_int
  \prg_replicate:nn { #1 } { \int_gincr:N \g_tmpa_int \int_to_arabic:n { \g_tmpa_int } & }
  #2 & #3 \\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\maiertable{3}{foo}{bar}

\medskip

\maiertable{10}{foo}{bar}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just for comparison, this is how you would do this is LuaTeX. The code below is in ConTeXt, but the LaTeX code should be equally straight forward.

```
\startluacode
  thirddata = thirddata or {}

  function thirddata.fancytable(n, s1, s2) 
    context.bTABLE()
    context.bTR()
    for i = 1, n do
      context.bTD() context(i) context.eTD()
    end
    context.bTD() context(s1) context.eTD()
    context.bTD() context(s2) context.eTD()
    context.eTABLE()
  end
\stopluacode

\define[3]\FancyTable{\ctxlua{thirddata.fancytable(#1,"#2", "#3")}}

\starttext
\FancyTable{5}{foo}{bar}
\stoptext
```

[image]