# Using token list of expl3 with array package leads to conflicts

Tags: tables, expl3

I use the syntax of `expl3` to type a table with increasing number.
The usage can be found here:
[Create tabular depending on counter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297919/create-tabular-depending-on-counter)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int {5}
\tl_clear:N \l_tmpa_tl
\int_step_inline:nn{\l_tmpa_int+1}{\tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl{|l}}
\tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl{|}
\begin{tabular}{\l_tmpa_tl}
  \int_step_inline:nn{\l_tmpa_int}{#1&} others
\end{tabular}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

The above codes produce an error:

```
! Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (\l_tmpa_tl): `c' used.
```

Without loading `array`, the codes work well.
The error seems due to `array`. Is there some methods to deal with this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `array` no expansion is performed to the mandatory argument to `tabular`. You can use `\exp_args:NnV \begin{tabular}\l_tmpa_tl`, but there are better ways to generate such a table preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \prg_replicate:nn { 6 } { |l } | }
\cs_set:Nn \__jiaopijie_temp:n { #1 & }
\exp_args:NnV \begin{tabular} \l_tmpa_tl
  \int_step_function:nN { 5 } \__jiaopijie_temp:n others
\end{tabular}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

[image]